Why does my Firebase Realtime Database sometimes send the entire collection, instead of just the updated data?
I subscription the change in the Firebase Realtime Database,
using the Go language listening at / and receiving the correct data change.
The data change will only have the data that was updated in the collection,
but sometimes the entire collection will be received,
and the all amount of data sent will be large. I would like to ask why this happens sometimes, and why the entire collection is sent?

My realtime database structure
-- my collection
    -- Data A
        -- Data A1
            -- Data A2
                -- Data A3
                    - Key A31
                    - Key A32
                    - Key A33
                    - Key A34
    -- Data B
        ...


The code is listening at the "/" path in the database and receiving the correct data changes.

The data change events only contain the data that was updated in the collection.
Receiving data
    -- Data A3
        - Key A31
        - Key A32
        - Key A33
        - Key A34


However, there are some rare instances where the entire collection is received, and the amount of data sent is large.
Receiving data
    -- my collection
        -- Data A
            -- Data A1
                -- Data A2
                    -- Data A3
                        - Key A31
                        - Key A32
                        - Key A33
                        - Key A34
        -- Data B
            ...



Here is my sample code for subscription
conf, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(verifyKeyByte, UserinfoEmailScope, FirebaseDatabaseScope)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
realtimeFirebaseURL := firego.New(fmt.Sprintf("%s", resource.FirebaseConfig.URL), conf.Client(oauth2.NoContext))
notifications := make(chan firego.Event)
if err := realtimeFirebaseURL.Watch(notifications); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer realtimeFirebaseURL.StopWatching()
round := 1
resource.WatchNotifications(notifications, conf, realtimeFirebaseURL, round)

resource.WatchNotifications() is function for read notification.

Are all documents in the collection updated? What is code that listens to changes?

Without seeing your minimal code that triggers the problem, and something like log output of both the cases, it'll be hard to say what could be going on.

@AlexMamo No just update like
-- Data A3
- Key A31
And we use golang lib zawabawa99 firego to subscription our firebase.

@FrankvanPuffelen I already update my sample code at my post. Thank you for a guide.

None of that code seems to show the actual problem, which is that you say you receive either partial data or complete data. Firebase should always be surfacing a complete snapshot of the data at the URL. So it likely depends on what your processing does, which is why we'll need to see a minimal repro of that too.
